# how to set read only body text in ck editor?

Tags: jquery

I tried like this
Example:
To disable **CKEditor**:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['TEXTAREA_NAME'].setReadOnly(true);
```

To enable CKEditor:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['TEXTAREA_NAME'].setReadOnly(false);
```

BUT it disable all options like **text-align**, **bold** so I need to set ReadOnly for body text with out affecting editing options...

Comment: Why do you need editing option if you can only read its just the same as not editing at all because it is read only.

Comment: i need to bold the text without changing it

Comment: you can try to add this `config.readOnly = true;` into the config file

Comment: i have tried this but it disable the edit options like bold, italic.etc